# WhatsApp not prompting to restore from Google Drive backup

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

Transferring WhatsApp from a Samsung S7 to a Samsung 10e.
Backedup to Google Drive as per instructions, 174mb of backup exists

Setup WhatsApp on the new phone (same number, SIM swapped over etc) and it doesn't prompt me to restore the backup.

Backup exists, I can see details if I go to Settings>Chats>Chat Backup, but I can't see any way to make it use that backup.  (I'm assuming if I click Backup, it will backup current state, not restore??)

How do I get it to use the backup it knows exists?

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but just experienced this on my own: I have to grant whatever permission that Whatsapp has asked for. Denying even one of them will lead to not showing the prompt.

Comment: I'm so glad you still shared about your experience: I've had the same issue today and not granting all permissions was what caused it for me too. Thank you so much. The fix then was to uninstall WhatsApp, reinstall it, grant everything and get prompted this time, restore, deny everything again.

Comment: Same case here; What an unfortunate bug

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assuming if I click Backup, it will backup current state, not restore??

Yes, don't tap backup. You will lose your entire backed up data. Also disable auto backup until the problem is solved.

Try reinstalling the app. This often helps.